# Protect Windows folder without encrypting the contents

Tags: security, apache

I want to protect the "www" folder in my Apache server. Checked some tools on the net like TrueCrypt, FolderEncrypt etc. All these encrypt the folder contents. If the www folder is encrypted, then my php won't work. Is there a way to lock the folder in windows without encrypting its contents.[ A little harder to crack then no lock at all]

Regards
Jad

Comment: What threat are you trying to protect yourself against?  If you're trying to prevent people who steal your computer/hard drive and reading the contents, then no method but encryption will protect you.  If you're trying to prevent people from accessing that folder from a remote directory, just turn off folder permissions (or better yet: don't share it in the first place).

Comment: Hi Travis, We are supposed to handover the WAMP server to a customer.
The whole PHP sourcecode will be in the www folder. I checked on PHP obfuscation first. Many were of the opinion that obfuscation is useless. So I was checking other approaches. Please let me know the best approach.

Comment: You're trying to hide your source code from the people who are using it?  I know of no techniques besides not using a scripting language.

Comment: Well, we don't have any choice of changing the code. And its not a hosted solution. So we have to hand over the WAMP server to the client and thinking about ways to secure the server, application and the code..

Comment: If the customer has your code on their server, then they will always have the technical means to read it.  There isn't really anything you can do about that - you'll just have to rely on the law to protect you from customers infringing your copyright.

Comment: What is it exactly you want to be able to do, and what do you want other people to not be able to do?  
  
You are looking at encryption software, but you don't want the folder encrypted?

Comment: @caf, that's the only good solution... Why dont you add it as an answer? @Jad, you could try asking at http://security.stackexchange.com